# How to calculate the total average in a while loop

Tags: c++

So I have this project from school that I have been at for a while Its an introductory c++ class in uni. The question as to calculate the total average grade of students after reading the data from the file. The problem I have now is that the instruction is to calculate the total average grade of all students but I don't know how to do so inside the while loop as you can see in the code and result below

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Global Variables
const string INPUT_FILE = "./students.txt";
const string OUTPUT_FILE = "./students_result.txt";

// Function Prototype
char letter_grade (int);

int main () {
    string student_name;
    int exam1, exam2, exam3, average_grade_per_student, total_average_all_student;
    ifstream student_info;
    char grade = ' ';

    student_info.open(INPUT_FILE, ios::in);

    if (!student_info) {
        cout << "Error occurred while opening " << INPUT_FILE << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (student_info >> student_name >> exam1 >> exam2 >> exam3) {
        // Calculate average grade of each student
        average_grade_per_student = (exam1 + exam2 + exam3) / 3;
        grade = letter_grade(average_grade_per_student);
        cout << "Student average grade: " << average_grade_per_student << " - " << grade << endl;
        total_average_all_student = (exam1 + exam2 + exam3) / 12;
        cout << "Total average for all students" << total_average_all_student << endl;
    }

    student_info.close();
    return 0;
}

//  Grades are calculated based on the table in the program introduction
char letter_grade (int average_grade_per_student) {
    char grade = ' ';

    if (average_grade_per_student >= 90) {
        grade = 'A';
        return grade;
    } else if ((average_grade_per_student >= 80) && (average_grade_per_student <= 89)) {
        grade = 'B';
        return grade;
    } else if ((average_grade_per_student >= 70) && (average_grade_per_student <= 79)) {
        grade = 'C';
        return grade;
    } else if ((average_grade_per_student >= 60) && (average_grade_per_student <= 69)) {
        grade = 'D';
        return grade;
    } else {
        grade = 'F';
        return grade;
    }
}
```

Results I get after running the code

```
Total average for all students21
Student average grade: 83 - B
Total average for all students20
Student average grade: 65 - D
Total average for all students16
Student average grade: 69 - D
Total average for all students17
Student average grade: 92 - A
Total average for all students23
Student average grade: 78 - C
Total average for all students19
Student average grade: 72 - C
Total average for all students18
Student average grade: 77 - C
Total average for all students19
Student average grade: 25 - F
Total average for all students6
Student average grade: 0 - F
Total average for all students0
Student average grade: 93 - A
Total average for all students23
Student average grade: 51 - F
Total average for all students12

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Help is highly appreciated

Comment: *my aim to solve the problem I am facing* We do not know what problem you are facing.

Comment: You're not acummulating the averages in `total_average_all_student`. You only need to do that.

Comment: Please don't tell us to let the code do the talking. It's kinda hard to know what the actual problem is, if you don't actually state what the problem is.

Comment: Keep a `sum_of_averages` in the `while` loop and keep a counter of the number of students. When you leave the `while` loop then get the `total_average_all_student = sum_of_averages / no_of_students;` (make sure the calculation is done with floating-point and doesn't suffer from integer division)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you my good sir

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your coding!